# How can I prevent firing setTimeout function if user performs actions too fast in js?

Tags: javascript

I have this part of code:

```js
$('#clientsfilter').on('input', function() {
     var string = $('#clientsfilter').val();
     if (string != "") {
         //console.log("input is not empty");
         var timeoutid = setTimeout(function() {
             // some stuff
             console.log("fired!");   
         }, 1500);
         console.log("timeoutid is "+timeoutid);
     }
     else
     {
        // console.log("input is empty");
     }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="clientsfilter" type="text" size="27">
```

When a user types something, it perform some actions after 1,5 seconds. But if a user will type one symbol after another too fass (time between symbols less than 1,5 seconds), the setTimeout() stuff will fire every time user adds symbol (or deletes). I want to prevent firing setTimeout function too many times, only if 1.5 seconds passed from last typing. I found information about

```
clearTimeout(timeoutid);
```

But how can I use it my situation?

Comment: You're looking for a debounce or throttle function.

Comment: What is "too many times"?

Comment: @Esszed — The question does explain that. *"the setTimeout() stuff will fire every time user adds symbol (or deletes)."* is what happens. *"I want to prevent firing setTimeout function too many times"* describes the former situation. *"only if 1.5 seconds passed **from last typing**"* is what is desired

Comment: @Quentin Got it! Thanks.

Comment: So, i found the solution. Thanks guys for telling about debounce. Now the code is like this:
`function debounce( callback, delay ) {
    let timeout;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout( timeout );
        timeout = setTimeout( callback, delay );
    }
}
function filterClients() {
    var string = $('#clientsfilter').val();
         if (string != "") {
         // stuff
         }
         else
         {
         }
}
const clientsfilter = document.getElementById("clientsfilter");
clientsfilter.addEventListener(
    "keyup",
    debounce( filterClients, 1500 )
);`